# How to pass class through an Angular Custom component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web-component

So I have a tooltip custom component that I need to be able to pass a class through to the underlying html, but not sure how to do it. Currently the tooltip (custom angular component) html looks like this:

```
<div role="tooltip" aria-haspopup="true" class="tooltip tooltip-md tooltip-bottom-right">
    <clr-icon class="icon-shape is-solid" shape="info-circle" size="20"></clr-icon>
    <div class="tooltip-content">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this custom component is like:

```
<tooltip>This is the text displayed.</tooltip>
```

What I need to be able to do is pass in a position so that the tooltip isn't always at bottom-right.  So I need to pass either a property or class or something so that in the custom component I can change the class of my div to "tooltip-top-right", "tooltip-bottom-left", etc... like so:

```
<tooltip class="tooltip-bottom-left">Tooltip text</tooltip>
```

or

```
<tooltip position="bottom-left">Tooltip text</tooltip>
```

And then inside the component's .ts or .html, assign the appropriate class to my div.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You could use mat-tooltip for this case.
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

It has built in matTooltipPosition directive so you wouldnt need to add any class to it.

1) Import the appropriate module in app.module.ts

```
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
```

2) Use the mat-tooltip selector and the matTooltipPosition input property

```
<button mat-raised-button
    matTooltip="Info about the action"
   [matTooltipPosition]='where you want it to be'
    aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
 </button>
```

more examples: 
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples